# How to convert a delimited string back to list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I have a delimited String as follows,

```
list1 = ['[107 207]', '[110 245]', '[115 282]', '[120 320]']
```

How can I convert this back to list in Python? The converted list should look like this:

```
[[107 207]
[110 245]
[115 282]
[120 320]]
```

I have tried **list1 = list1.split(",")**. But, when I print list[0] I'm getting this,

```
['[107 207]'
```

instead of getting this,

```
[107 207]
```

Also, trying list1 = ***[int(e) for e in list1.split(',')]*** gave me an error as follows:

```
"invalid literal for int() with base 10: \"['[107 207]'\""
```

Answer (score 0):

One option, using a nested list comprehension along with `re.findall` to extract all digits:

```py
list1 = ['[107 207]', '[110 245]', '[115 282]', '[120 320]']
output = [[int(y) for y in re.findall(r'\d+', x)] for x in  list1]
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
[[107, 207], [110, 245], [115, 282], [120, 320]]
```

There is probably a way to do this without invoking regex, but the `int()` cast seems mandatory to me, given that the input numbers start off inside a string.

Comment: This for me works on the small set that I mentioned here but gives output like [[], [], [], [1], [0], [7], [], [2], [0], [7] ...........] on a larger list. I dont know why!

Comment: Add the real data to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could strip the brackets off of the ends of each element. This method could probably be cleaner, but it *is* done in pure Python with no imports or regex.

```py
input = ['[107 207]', '[110 245]', '[115 282]', '[120 320]']

output = [[int(ii) for ii in i.lstrip("[").rstrip("]").split(" ")] for i in input]
```

This returns exactly what you wanted:

```py
[[107, 207], [110, 245], [115, 282], [120, 320]]
```

Here's a human-readable form of the code to help visualize what is going on:

```py
output = []

for item in input:
    itemString = item.lstrip("[")
    itemString = itemString.rstrip("]")
    itemList = itemString.split(" ")
    itemNumbers = [int(ii) for ii in itemList]
    output.append(itemNumbers)
```

Comment: Gives me an error "invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' ' "

Comment: @anjali That both valid answers are failing indicates to me that your data is the problem, and maybe you have some non numerical values.

Comment: @anjali I agree with Tim; both methods work well on the data set that you gave us; if you are using a slightly different data set format, then you should edit your question to reflect it.

Comment: @Tim seems you are right. I copied the entire String and tried it in Python3 command line and it works fine.

Comment: @anjali So are both of our methods working?

Comment: Yes, they are!. Thank you so much.

Comment: I found the issue, In order for this to work "item" in input should return this  '[107 207]' for input[0]. But when I directly read the delimited string from the .ini file and print input[0] I get  the first element of the string which is  the square bracket "["  instead of the list element which is causing this issue.